# DC Chopper Drive for Brushed DC Motors

Tags: dc-motor

This is, sort of, in continuation to my earlier question: [DC Chopper Drive for Brushed DC Separately Excited Motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/444850/dc-chopper-drive-for-brushed-dc-separately-excited-motor)

So, from all the details I have gathered over time (2019-2021), I think the following topology should provide close-to-unity power-factor for driving a Brushed DC Motor (1000 kW) :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq9gdv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To minimize heat sink size, the rectifier is conceived to be a synchronous rectifier, instead of a diode rectifier, and with a separate power factor correction stage.

The idea of this system has sprung up, because high power dc drives in mining etc, are typically not run at their maximum speeds, which results in low power factor and increased fuel costs or utility penalties.

So I am looking for expert opinions on the following points.

1. Are there any specific electrical pitfalls that should be kept in mind while designing such a system?
2. Does this look like a good arrangement, electrically or does it feel like overkill?
3. Cost-wise, is it prudent to go through all this exercise of converting existing SCR drives, to something like to above?
4. Space-wise, I think this arrangement will have many more items than the existing 6 pulse SCR bridges. Here, the 6 SCRs shall be replaced by 6 IGBTs, and in addition, there would be one reactor and one IGBT for the PFC stage, one Diode for the DC Link part, one IGBT for chopping the DC, and one Diode for freewheeling. There will also be a DC link capacitor (or a bank of them), and snubbers for each IGBT etc. Is there anything I am missing here?

Input is 3 phase, 600V AC.

Best Regards

Vishal

Comment: What are you trying to ask? Do you want someone's opinion on this simple block diagram? Also, "What are the pitfalls I should be wary about in the design of such a system?" is not a specific question.

Comment: Who knows? Probably you'd need a reactor on the network or even a sinus filter, I don't quite understand the problem using the SCR rectifier, beside that it produces a high harmonics. This super trooper device shall eliminate all this, but at what cost.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič . Thanks for your comment. Actually, there is no problem with using an SCR rectifier...but people looking to save on the cost of fuel for their DG sets or the high penalties from the utility company are looking for a way to drive their existing motors, at a higher power factor. In the SCR rectifier world, PF as low as 0.5 is not very uncommon. The other option they have been provided with is to use a VFD, and change all their motors to AC motoros. I am looking for a middle path.

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth, Thanks for your comment. Yes, I am looking for frank views from experts on this general electrical arrangement. I am also looking for some specific electrical issues and corner cases etc that I should look for in the design of such a system.  Let me add an edit.

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that brushed motors make sparks which can be bad in mines. And brushes wear and have other limitations which is why no one wants to use brushed motors anywhere past a certain size. Have you looked into these aspects before deciding to go with a brushed motor? The motors being run at low speed you are referring to are being run straight off the line without the disadvantages of brushes. If they want to improve PF, they connect a VFD to it.

Comment: @DKNguyen, it's True that there will be sparks at the commutator end, however, these motors are completely and forcefully air purged. Purging starts even before the Field supply is established and continues for sometime after the armature and field supplies have been switched Off. Such DC Motors have been used since a long time. To go for VFDs, all Motors need to be changed into AC motors. And all this, only for getting better Power Factor.